# Getting a widget inside a window by a custom attribute - tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

let's say I have a frame being created in a function and I give it an id like this:

```py
def initMainFrame(window):
  frame = ttk.Frame(window, borderwidth=5, relief="ridge", padding=(40,40)) #create frame
  frame.myId = "mainFrame"
  frame.pack()
```

How do I access the created frame in a different scope using the `myId` attribute I gave it?
If there is a more convenient way of doing this feel free to let me know.

Comment: Why not make the variable global? Instead of ids in python we usually use variable names

Comment: What I am trying to do is have a button which deletes this new frame when it is clicked and certain conditions are met. I mean, I could have a global variable called currentFrame and set it to the new frame and then access it like that but I was just seeing if it was possible using something similar to what I posted.

Comment: `return frame`? If not, you need to provide more context and code.

Comment: @GarXik Well you can go through all of the children of `window` using `window.winfo_children()` and look for the one with that id but using a global variable is much better.

Comment: @TheLizzard did have it in mind to do just that but I am sure there's a more efficient way than having to loop through all the children.

Comment: @GarXik There isn't. Also martineau suggested that you return the frame so you can store it in a variable. Does that work for you?

Comment: Okay then, I guess I will try to work using a global variable then. Thank you both @TheLizzard & martineau

Comment: @TheLizzard Just a question, I am not a regular user of python btw. To declare a variable without a value do I just write the variable name or do I always have to include "None" as a value.

Comment: @GarXik In python you can't have a variable without a value so yes you have to use `<variable name> = None`

Answer (score 0):

You can try giving widgets unique names.

```py
>>> import tkinter as tk
>>> root = tk.Tk()
>>> frame = tk.Frame(root, name="frame_name")
>>> root.nametowidget("frame_name")
<tkinter.Frame object .frame_name>
>>> button = tk.Button(frame, name="button_name")
>>> root.nametowidget(".frame_name.button_name")
<tkinter.Button object .frame_name.button_name>
>>> frame.winfo_name()
'frame_name'
>>>
```